# jQuery: Adding context to a selector is much faster than refining your selector?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I just noticed that adding context to the selector is much faster than refining your selector.

`$('li',$('#bar')).append('bla');`

Is twice as faster than:

`$('#bar li').append('bla');`

Is this generally true?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> adding context to the selector is much
>   faster than refining your selector

This is true in the general case. With respect to your specific examples however it is not necessarily true for jQuery <= 1.2.6.

Up to and including jQuery 1.2.6 the selector engine worked in a "top down" (or "left to right") manner. Meaning that both your examples would operate like this (roughly):

```
var root = document.getElementById('bar');
return root.getElementsByTagName('li');
```

jQuery 1.3.x  (ie, [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which jQuery embeds) [introduced a "bottom up" (or "right to left") approach](http://www.slideshare.net/jeresig/recent-changes-to-jquerys-internals) to querying the DOM. So `$('#bar li')` now becomes (roughly):

```
var results = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    while(parent) {
        if(parent.id == 'bar') {
            results.push(element)
            break;
        }
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
}
return results
```

There are benefits and downsides to both approaches. You found one of the downsides.

**Edit**: just found out from [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/msg/97555a542602fc74) that Sizzle trunk now makes a special exemption of selectors where `#id` is first. It uses that as the root context, speeding things up a bit. This should diminish if not eliminate the speed differences you are seeing.