# find('a,b') is slower than find('a')+find('b'), why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsperf's link](http://jsperf.com/find-a-b-vs-find-a-find-b)

I'm not a jQuery expert(not even a good user), i haven't studied the whole source code of it (only a little part which can't help me solve this problem).

Can somebody explain this for me?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411143/jquery-selector-performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
$p.find("input,select");
```

...uses the native `querySelectorAll`.

This:

```
$p.find("input");
$p.find("select");
```

...uses the native `getElementsByTagName`.

The `getElementsByTagName` is simply faster, perhaps because it is a very simple selection, and has been around longer, giving it more time for optimization.

Also, when jQuery uses `querySelectorAll`, it does so from the `document` even if you're searching from a specified context, so this has an impact. To narrow the results to the context you provided, it changes your selector to use the ID of the element, or gives it a temporary one if non exists.

---

I [updated your test](http://jsperf.com/find-a-b-vs-find-a-find-b/2) to give a few more comparisons. Shows that if you're really concerned about performance, you should use the native API.

Comment: @Narendra: Thanks for the link. Good illustration of the difference, and shows once again how Opera has given specific attention to `qSA`.

Comment: Very interesting. `getElementsByTagName("input")` is about 200 times faster than `$p.find("input")` even though `$p.find` uses `getElementsByTagName`. As you said, jQuery calls must be slowing down things quite a bit!

Answer (score 0):

What Ӫ_._Ӫ said above is true, but do note that the results aren't necessarily equivalent, since the first will (AFAIK) return `input`s and `select`s in interspersed document order and the second will return them one after each other. This may not matter for your application, but it's something to note.