# Javascript performance: Caching vs No Caching - weird results

Tags: jquery, dom, performance

I am trying to optimize some basic jquery script that traverses and hides/shows some unordered lists.

Here's the testcase in jsperf: http://jsperf.com/caching-vs-no-caching

I run the test in two browsers: Chrome and IE7/IE8 and surprisingly the cached case is slower - by a little bit but still.

The unoptimized version is:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.menuManipulation = function() {
    this.parents().show();
  };
})( jQuery );

$('.menu-vertical li.selected').menuManipulation();
$(".menu-vertical li.selected > ul.static").show();
$('li.static').has('ul').addClass("with-child");
```

and the cached one:

```
(function($) {  
    $.fn.menuManipulation = function() {
    this.parents().show();
    };
})(jQuery);

var menu = $('.menu-vertical');
menu.find('li.selected').menuManipulation();
menu.find('li.selected > ul.static').show();
menu.find('li.static').has('ul').addClass("with-child");
```

Could someone explain what am I doing wrong and why does the cached version seem to be slower?

Comment: I would venture a guess that the benefit you get from the cached version doesn't outweigh the overhead of caching the data, so that it takes a little more total time to gather and store all the data for caching purposes than it does to retrieve and return the specific data that you want for the non-cached version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Selectors are actually pretty fast, but `find` is slow as hell. Your cached version has introduced multiple `find` calls - that is what is slow.

Slightly longer answer: You only really get benefir from caching the jQuery collection if you keep re-using it as-is. Take a look at this test case where the cached version clearly runs faster: http://jsperf.com/cachingjq

Comment: This. In my opinion, if you're using `find` a lot, there's a good chance you need to re-evaluate your selectors

Comment: Even though the question is answered, what would be a good simple alternative to improve the original code if find is out of the question?

Answer (score 2):

George,

Try this in your 'cached' case and see what the performance difference is:

```
(function($) {  
    $.fn.menuManipulation = function() {
        this.parents().show();
    };
})(jQuery);

var menu = $('.menu-vertical');
$('li.selected', menu).menuManipulation();
$('li.selected > ul.static', menu).show();
$('li.static', menu).has('ul').addClass("with-child");
```

Comment: thanks, smart use of the comma-separated selectors to define the context. Didn't come to mind.

Comment: seems to be faster indeed. By 2-3%

Answer (score 1):

It's debatable as to whether `find()` is 'slow as hell', or infact fast as hell. Your performance issues could depend on the version of jQuery your using, or the structure of your DOM.

See here for the other side of the argument for `find()` performance:
[jQuery selector performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411143/jquery-selector-performance), 
http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/jquery_selector_performance_testing

Benchmark test: [Find() Vs Selector](http://jsperf.com/find-vs-directly-selecting)

Comment: This article is enlightening. I wonder if the jQuery version has an impact to this. (whether you're using a legacy version or a latest version..)

Answer (score 1):

Cache the elements your actually going to be working on, in your case the 'li' elements.

```
var menu = $('.menu-vertical li');
menu.filter('.selected').children('ul.static').show().end().menuManipulation();
menu.filter('.static').has('ul').addClass("with-child");
```

Your "optimized" cache version is actually less optimized because of the additional and redundant searching for the li elements.

Comment: to add some context and help the query?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos I suppose for context you could change the variable to menuItems in my example. In terms of helping the query, caching the parent forces you to repeat the li selector in each of the subsequent statements, which is not an optimization over your "unoptimized" example. When I look to optimize a selector, $('?'),  I try to minimize the $('?').length of selectors first, starting at the highest level and working down.