# How to disable classes with same name and differnt instance in jquery?

Tags: jquery, instance, show-hide, web-controls

I am having a `webControl` with 3 `TextBoxes` and I am using this `webControl` in same page but twice with 2 instances.

I want to hide one text box from one control and other text box from the other control .

```
<uc1:VoyageSelector runat="server" ID="VoyageSelector1"  Instance="1" />

<uc1:VoyageSelector runat="server" ID="VoyageSelector2"  Instance="2" />
```

This control is having text box classes as:

```
$(".vss-week-picker").val(); 
$('.vs-voyage-picker').val(); 
$('.vs-vessel-display').val();
```

When I disable:

```
$(".vss-week-picker").hide();
```

Both Controls Week `TextBox` is getting hidden.
How can I solve this problem of hiding one instance class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the id of the element that the control produces, and use it to select your targets.

For example, if it produces a parent element with id 'VoyageSelector1', then you hide its textboxes like this :

```
$('.vss-week-picker','#ContentPlaceHolder1_VoyageSelector2_tblVoyageSelector').‌​hide();
```

Comment: I just gave an example of how to do it, of course it won't work if you copy paste. can you post the html that's produced?

Comment: $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_VoyageSelector2_tblVoyageSelector .vs-service-picker").hide();
this way its wokring

Comment: that's what I said. get the generated id and use it. I didn't know the exact id, `VoyageSelector1` was an example. Just replace `VoyageSelector1` with `ContentPlaceHolder1_VoyageSelector2_tblVoyageSelector` in my code, it's the same. You wil get this: `$('.vss-week-picker','#ContentPlaceHolder1_VoyageSelector2_tblVoyageSelector').hide();`

Comment: Ok. I'm glad it works. And to be precise, this way is (maybe only theoriticaly) faster. See here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650860/jquery-adding-context-to-a-selector-is-much-faster-than-refining-your-selector

Answer (score 0):

i did this in past, don't remember exactly, may this works

```
$("[id ^= VoyageSelector1] .vss-week-picker").hide();
```

Comment: $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_VoyageSelector2_tblVoyageSelector .vs-service-picker").hide(); this way its wokring ..., Thnks :)